# Should I increase the spacing between paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, typography

By default, as far as I know, there is no spacing between paragraphs in Latex (I'm using Overleaf). The paragraphs look like this:

[image]

It is possible to set a spacing between paragraphs using

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

which looks like

[image]

I know this is a matter of taste but I personally prefer the spacing between the paragraphs and my question is if this is commonly preferred. What are reasons in favor or against using the spacing?

Comment: If you use a non-zero \parskip, you should  set the paragraph indent to 0.

Comment: Good call, I didn't know that

Comment: This is a opinion-based question. If your are writing for a journal, or it is your thesis, etc. you will probably be asked to follow some guidelines regarding style. If it is for your own personal archive, classes, reports, etc, you do what you think is more clear and suitable. It doesn't mean everyone will agree with you, but that's another issue for another debate. Normally, I edit it with the package `setspace` -> `\singlespacing` or `\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: don't set `\parskip` directly use a package such as `\usepackage{parskip}` or a class designed for that, otherwise you will get extra space in lots of unexpected places where things internally are paragraphs. (but generally things look better wihout hvrtical space)